# Pass params or conf when trigger a DAG at AirflowUI

Tags: airflow

Airflow cli support an option to pass confs.

```
airflow trigger_dag --conf {"file_variable": "/path/to/file"} dag_id
```

But at UI it doesn’t provide a way to give parameters when trigger on UI.

Is my understand right?

Why they do not provide an UI options to set conf?

When I use Jenkins, It is very common to give/change then give parameters to a JOB build.

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is correct. There is currently no way to provide configuration to a dag_run when triggering it via the Web UI.

The way around this is to trigger the dag externally, which can be done a few different ways:

- through the [Airflow CLI](https://airflow.apache.org/cli.html#trigger_dag) (as you mentioned)
- using a [Local client](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/api/client/local_client.py) from within a python script
- through the [Airflow REST API](https://airflow.apache.org/api.html)

These all allow you to provide a configuration when triggering a dag run.